# Facebook Graph API error "Received Invalid JSON reply"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

we are using Facebook Graph API to implement Facebook sharing from our web application.

We are calling graph API to re-scrape url to be shared using post request as  below:

```
$jq.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/?id'+rescrapeUrl,
        data : {scrape: true},
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data); 
           },
         error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);     
         }
      });
```

We received response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1357046,
    "message": "Received Invalid JSON reply.",
    "type": "http"
  }
}
```

[Facebook Graph API Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLdUw.png)

We tried scraping the same URL using web interface
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

and it scraps successfully.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should properly escape the URL before you put it into another URL as a parameter value ... Or just send it as an actual POST parameter to begin with.

Comment: I got this error because I queried the `rating_count` of a Facebook page. It seems that property doesn’t work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes below meta-tag creating problem `<meta property="og:image:alt" content="some content" />` even if you include it with the other tags including og:image

So, you can try to scrape after removing this og:image:alt tag, then may be scrape working fine.